# C-Style upcast and downcast involving private inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting

Consider the following piece of code :-

```
class A {};

class B : private A {};

B* bPtr1 = new B;
// A* aPtr1 = bPtr1; // error
// A* aPtr2 = static_cast<A*>(bPtr1); // error
A* aPtr3 = (A*)bPtr1;
B* bPtr2 = (B*)aPtr3;
```

The C-style cast discards the private inheritance while both the implicit and `static_cast` fail (also `dynamic_cast`). Why ?
If C-style casts are just bit-fiddling, how are C++ casts implemented i.e. how do they know the type of inheritance from memory footprint?

After bPtr1 is casted to aPtr3, i will have to use another C-style cast to downcast to B as again both `static_cast` and `dynamic_cast` fail. So, is bPtr2 guaranteed to be good?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Related q (with better answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/844816/c-style-upcast-and-downcast-involving-private-inheritance?rq=1

Answer (score 7):

The standard states in 5.4.7 that C-style casts can actually do *more than any sequence of new-style casts can do* -- specifically including casting from a pointer-to-derived to pointer-to-base even when the base class is inaccessible, which is precisely what happens here with private inheritance.  (Why this should be allowed, and in particular why it should be allowed only for C-style casts, is utterly beyond me; but it's undeniably allowed.)

So dribeas is right, compilers are obliged to handle the OP's C-style pointer conversion correctly, even when `B` inherits from multiple base classes.  My own testing with MSVC++8 and MinGW confirms his results in practice -- when `B` inherits from multiple base classes, the compiler will adjust pointers when converting a `B*` to an `A*` or vice versa so that the correct object or subobject is identified.

I stand by my assertion that you ought to derive `B` *publicly* from `A` if you ever intend to treat a `B` as an `A`, since using private inheritance instead *necessitates* using C-style casts.

Comment: I have just tested it with gcc 4.0 on MacOSX and the code does not break. Calling a virtual method defined in A does actually call the B version and the program does not die. If there is an intermediate conversion to void* then it erroneously calls the B version of a virtual B method (the first method in the vtable in my test). This does not mean that it is not undefined though (I don't know).

I agree that C style casts should be avoided and that the C++ versions are more cumbersome so that all alarms go off, but I cannot upvote this answer for the previous reason.

Comment: @dribeas: Intriguing, I'm gonna do some tests myself in a moment. One thing -- was your X by any chance empty of data elements? In that particular case, the Empty Base Optimisation would kick in, allowing the A subobject to live at the same address as the B object. But if X contains data members, I believe the A subobject cannot exist at the same address, leading to breakage. (In any case, that wrinkle should have been mentioned in my post.)

Comment: Well, time to eat some humble pie... It turns out the standard states that C-style casts can do *more than any sequence of new-style casts can do* in 5.4.7 -- specifically including casting from a pointer-to-derived to pointer-to-base even when the base class is inaccessible, which is precisely what happens here with private inheritance. So dribeas is right, compilers are obliged to perform the necessary pointer adjustments so that the code I posted will work. My own testing with MSVC++8 and MinGW confirms his testing.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ casts are enforced by the compiler (not the linker). It's not that private inheritance causes a different class layout; it's that the compiler will forbid you from casting a pointer to a derived class to a pointer to its base class if the inheritance is not public, based on the declaration of the class.

Answer (score -1):

The existing answers are great, but one bit of information you may find helpful relates to this:

> C-style casts are just bit-fiddling

If you use an old-style cast between two pointer types, the compiler usually wouldn't need to fiddle with any bits. You're telling the compiler that you want to treat a location of memory as if it contained some type (because you know that it effectively does), so the compiler does nothing at all at runtime to modify the contents of memory. Casting merely disables type safety at compile time.

Comment: -1: Nonsense. The use of C-style casts in C++ may result in a `reinterpret_cast`, a `static_cast` or a `const_cast` (or a combination). At least one of these is certainly more than "just bit-fiddling".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think that's probably why I said "usually wouldn't".

Answer (score -4):

> If C-style casts are just bit-fiddling, how are C++ casts implemented i.e. how do they know the type of inheritance from memory footprint?

C-style casts in C++ mean more than meets the eye. They are technically the only way to ask the compiler to choose the right cast operator required for conversion. For the same reason, this is better than using `reinterpret_cast`. The latter is implementation defined.

It seems there is a lot of confusion around C-style casts. Remember, no tool is safe until you know how to use it. The same applies to the C-style cast. The point of having a C-style cast is to ask the compiler to choose the safest and most portable conversion for a given pair of types. This may trigger a change from `static_cast` to `reinterpret_cast` silently and introduce errors. The point is: you need to know what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know the 'implementation-defined' aspect of the reinterpret_cast.

Comment: @dirkgently: Yes, C-style casts ask the compiler to choose the right cast for you, but this makes them **worse** than reinterpret_cast -- at least with reinterpret_cast, you are making your intention to do something "naughty" obvious (greppable in fact), thereby easing maintenance. A C-style cast is allowed to, and will often, perform a reinterpret_cast under the hood **without telling you**. -1.

Comment: Casts are dicey at best. So, I'd rather have the compiler than choose something worse. I would rather use a C-style cast than reinterpret_cast.

Comment: OK, I think a terrible analogy is in order :) If someone sent you a bomb in the mail, would you rather it looked like a bomb, or looked like any other mail? reinterpret_cast is a bomb that looks like a bomb, a C-style cast is a normal-looking piece of mail that might contain a bomb.

Comment: I don't think that's how I would read the code. I'd read it: Okay, here's a bomb, and I've called in the experts. But beyond that, all bets are off.

Comment: -1 for using C-style casts, which will silently cast away constness.

Comment: @Thomas L Holaday: C-style casting can be used with consts. However, it seems the whole point of this post is lost on most.

Comment: O.K.peace. I opened-up D&E, Stroustrup says C-Style casting is at best a 'historical burden'. Whether C-Style casts use 'reinterpret_cast' under the hood or have their own implementation is i think undefined in the C++ standard. So, always use C++ casts unless u know what u r doing :-). In my case one of the developers conjured this up to allow him program using the supertype 'A' though the design was not for it.

Comment: @dirkgently - it sounds like you are encouraging ignorance ("I have a bomb... all bets are off").  Casts (C or C++) do have well-defined behavior, and no bets should be off.  A developer using this part of the language should know *exactly* what it is doing, or step away from the keyboard.

Comment: I've discovered (embarrassingly) that there are some things that can *only* be accomplished using C-style casts, and converting from a pointer-to-derived to a pointer-to-INACCESSIBLE-base is one of them, so my suggestion to use reinterpret_cast instead can't actually be used in this particular case. But dirkgently, I still think your reasoning is suspect -- when you do something "tricky", surely it's best to draw attention to it if possible. (Or do you think a C-style cast already draws enough attention?)

Comment: @Tom: You are quoting me out of context.
@j_random_hacker: To me any cast draws a frown.

Comment: @Tom: I am specifically trying to point out where you can rely on C-style casts. I am not trying to encourage ignorance, rather, on knowing what semantics you unleash with a particular syntax and using it effectively. I rest my case here.